# Why is PowerShell version behind on my Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

Windows 10 philosophy was that Microsoft pushes all updates. But my PowerShell is at version 5.0 and I noticed current release is 7.1.1

Isn't PowerShell integral part of Windows 10? Why does Windows updates not update it?

It seems like this is essentially a stand alone application that we have to maintain ourselves and download the latest version independently? This is not even covered by Windows updates?

Comment: Hi @zar - Are you satisfied with the answer I provided below by chance?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because Microsoft wants it to work this way at the moment with Windows 10 since they designed and developed the functionality to work this way. Whether or not this changes in the future is to be determined then so stay tuned like the rest of us with this regard.

1. As per the Microsoft [Using PowerShell 7 side-by-side with Windows PowerShell 5.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.1#using-powershell-7-side-by-side-with-windows-powershell-51) post...

   > PowerShell 7 is designed to coexist with Windows PowerShell 5.1. The
   > following features ensure that your investment in PowerShell is
   > protected and your migration to PowerShell 7 is simple.
   >
   > [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.1#using-powershell-7-side-by-side-with-windows-powershell-51)

   [PowerShell 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-powershell-7-0/) is not really an integral part of the Windows 10 Operating System at the moment. It appears they want people to make a conscious decision to install it explicitly since it's meant to coexist with PowerShell 5.1 at the moment so that's how it works.

---

2. Furthermore per all the methods mentioned on the [Installing PowerShell on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1) post...

   > Microsoft supports the installation methods in this document. There
   > may be other methods of installation available from other sources.
   > While those tools and methods may work, Microsoft cannot support those
   > methods.
   >
   > [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1#installation-support)

   Since Microsoft develops and maintains the [PowerShell 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-powershell-7-0/) functionality with their Windows 10 Operating System, it seems that this is by design per that development for the reason they state.

   For the methods of installing it otherwise, they state that too in the [Installing PowerShell on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1) post so at the moment this is why, and Windows Update is not  listed there.

Comment: The short answer is because this is the way MS wants it to work at the moment with Windows 10. Whether or not that changes in the future is to be determined then I suppose. Stay tuned just like the rest of us @zar.

Comment: So PS 7 is not really an integral part of the Windows 10 OS, so they want people to make a conscious decision to explicitly install it since it is meant to coexist.

Comment: Which means, effectively, that the Powershell team never has to fix any bugs on the version of Powershell running on 99% of machines.  That's a pretty sweet gig.

Comment: Might have to ask folks that have experience lurking around on GitHub and such if this means that specifically because if anyone has seen them patch bugs related to PS 5.1, then that may not always be the case. I look at it as needed for backwards compatibility with processes companies and folks have gotten setup in their environments. I'm guilty myself of having slews of things developed all over the place to work with PS 5.1 as defined, tested, and rolled out. I need to spend more time using VS Code and working with PS 7 but that's not always practical for all companies with one sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

> But my PowerShell is at version 5.0 and I noticed current release is 7.1.1

The current version of PowerShell is 5.1 while the current version of the open source project formally known as PowerShell Core is PowerShell 7.1

> It seems like this is essentially a stand alone application that we have to maintain ourselves and download the latest version independently?

PowerShell 7.1 at this time is indeed a separate download and is NOT considered a Windows component.

Microsoft has in the past indicated that PowerShell (Core) is the next version of PowerShell.  They have also indicated development of PowerShell (Core) 7.1 is aligned with the development of .NET (Core) 5 [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-team-may-2020-update/)

> This is not even covered by Windows updates?

While PowerShell 5.1 is built into Windows, it is not updated through Windows Update, since all development on the 5.1 branch has ceased. PowerShell 5.1 lifecycle is based on Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

Microsoft has not released the timeline when PowerShell (Core) 7.1 and .NET (Core) 5 will replace .NET 4.8 and PowerShell 5.1 respectively.

Source: [PowerShell Support Lifecycle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-support-lifecycle?view=powershell-7.1)

Microsoft in 2019 said that PowerShell 7 would eventually be distributed as a side-by-side feature on Windows.  However, they indicate at the time, development would have to be aligned to that of Windows.

> We are planning on eventually shipping PowerShell 7 in Windows as a side-by-side feature with Windows PowerShell 5.1, but we still need to work out some of the details on how you will manage this inbox version of PowerShell 7.
>
> And since the .NET Core timeline doesn’t align with the Windows timeline, we can’t say right now when it will show up in a future version of Windows 10 or Windows Server.

Source: [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/the-next-release-of-powershell-powershell-7/) and [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/)

Comment: any updates on this roughly a year later?

Comment: @sommmen - No; There are no updates other than the fact updates to PowerShell 7.x have been released. PowerShell 7.x still has to be manually installed even on Windows 11 21H2 and 22H2